# Session creation in Google appengine (Python) - simple auth failing

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, session-cookies, facebook-login

We have an application running on Google Appengine (Python 2.7), that uses [Simple Auth](https://code.google.com/p/gae-simpleauth/) for login and webapps2 framework.
We are currently only supporting Facebook login.

**Problem:** At times the facebook login - session creation does not work properly.
This doesn't happen always and it affects only 10 % of the overall traffic on the site.
The callback from Facebook auth to our site comes properly, we are also able to get the Facebook auth token. But the session creation alone fails.

**Control flow:** 
1) User clicks on "Login with Facebook" button on our page
2) User is redirected to Facebook for permissions (if its the first time login)
3) User is redirected back to our site on giving proper authorization in Facebook
4) User auth token is obtained on our site and we fetch user details from Facebook graph API using this token
5) A session is created and the cookie header is set on the response object (Place where issue occurs currently)
6) User is redirected to our dashboard (Dashboard is a screen that is displayed only for logged in users. So if the session/cookie is not created properly, the user will be redirected back to login page).

**Remedy already tried:**
My first guess was that the session creation is taking more time than the next line of code to execute. This can happen in case the session creation is an async process. So I have included a small delay between the session creation line and the next line. The idea was to given enough time for the uncommitted changes to be committed. Additionally, if the session was not really created at the end of the sleep time, I attempt to recreate the session object.

```
ok, user = self.auth.store.user_model.create_user(auth_id, **_attrs)
logging.info("creating user : "+str(ok)+" | user" +str(user))
if ok:
    self.auth.set_session(self.auth.store.user_to_dict(user))
    logging.info("User: "+str(self.auth.get_user_by_session()))
    if( self.auth.get_user_by_session() is None ):
        logging.info("Existing user logging in.. But the set session didn't work So wait for sometime")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if( self.auth.get_user_by_session() is None ):
            logging.info("Existing user logging in.. But the set session didn't work So try again")
            self.auth.set_session(self.auth.store.user_to_dict(user))
```

But the above-mentioned technique is not working. And so, there is a flaw in my diagnosis.

Requesting help in solving this problem. Please let me know if you need more information on the same.

Answer (score 0):

In general, waiting is a poor excuse for synchronization.

In either case you'll want to dig into your auth library to investigate.
You don't want auth.set_session to be async.  Make it synchronous.  That should make life easier.

Find out how get_user_by_session() works.  The problem you describe sounds a lot like eventual consistency behavior.  This may happen if get_user_by_session() issues a datastore query operation, which may return eventually consistent results.  For your get_user_by_session() operation, you want strongly consistent results, so the library should be using a datastore get operation.  In fact, since you just created the user and session, the library should have cached that information and shouldn't need to hit the datastore at all.

The library being python, you should be able to step through the library code and figure out what's going on.